# How to debug WebBrowser mshtml.dll c0000005

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, browser, unmanaged

I am using WebBrowser control with .NET 4.0 and getting random crashes. The time in which the application crashes varies, although the use of the application is exactly the same.

Here's the problem description that windows provides:

```
   <EventType>APPCRASH</EventType>
   <Parameter0>MyApp.vshost.exe</Parameter0>
   <Parameter1>11.0.50727.1</Parameter1>
   <Parameter2>5011d445</Parameter2>
   <Parameter3>mshtml.dll</Parameter3>
   <Parameter4>9.0.8112.16476</Parameter4>
   <Parameter5>5126ee6c</Parameter5>
   <Parameter6>c0000005</Parameter6>   
   <Parameter7>00262cd4</Parameter7>
```

How can I debug this problem? I tried opening the dump file and the stacktrace I got is nothing really useful (is it?):

```
    ntdll.dll!_NtRaiseException@12()  + 0x12 bytes  
ntdll.dll!_NtRaiseException@12()  + 0x12 bytes  
wininet.dll!_ResizeBuffer@12()  + 0x40 bytes    
mshtml.dll!RaiseFailFastExceptionFilter()  + 0x24 bytes 
mshtml.dll!GlobalWndProc()  + 0x4562d bytes 
msvcrt.dll!@_EH4_CallFilterFunc@8()  + 0x12 bytes   
ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler2@20()  + 0x26 bytes    
ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler@20()  + 0x24 bytes 
ntdll.dll!_RtlDispatchException@8()  + 0xd3 bytes   
ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()  + 0xf bytes   
mshtml.dll!CHtmParse::Prepare()  + 0x2f bytes   
mshtml.dll!CHtmPost::Broadcast()  + 0xf bytes   
mshtml.dll!CHtmPost::Exec()  + 0xbd bytes   
mshtml.dll!CHtmPost::RunNested()  + 0x6e bytes  
mshtml.dll!CHtmLoad::Write()  + 0x165 bytes 
mshtml.dll!CHtmCtx::Write()  + 0x2a bytes   
mshtml.dll!CDocument::write()  + 0x185 bytes    
mshtml.dll!Method_void_SAFEARRAYPVARIANTP()  + 0x30 bytes   
mshtml.dll!CBase::ContextInvokeEx()  + 0x1e5 bytes  
mshtml.dll!CBase::InvokeEx()  + 0x2b bytes  
mshtml.dll!DispatchInvokeCollection()  - 0x166e80 bytes 
mshtml.dll!CDocument::InvokeEx()  + 0xcb bytes  
mshtml.dll!CBase::VersionedInvokeEx()  + 0x37 bytes 
mshtml.dll!CBase::PrivateInvokeEx()  + 0x4d bytes   
mshtml.dll!CBase::varInvokeEx()  + 0x44 bytes   
jscript9.dll!HostDispatch::CallInvokeEx()  + 0xca bytes 
jscript9.dll!HostDispatch::InvokeMarshaled()  + 0x3d bytes  
jscript9.dll!HostDispatch::InvokeByDispId()  + 0x1dc bytes  
jscript9.dll!DispMemberProxy::DefaultInvoke()  + 0x22 bytes 
jscript9.dll!DispMemberProxy::DefaultInvoke()  + 0x20 bytes 
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction()  + 0x87 bytes   
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_CallFld()  + 0x4d bytes  
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()  - 0x190f7 bytes  
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::ProcessThunk()  + 0x65 bytes    
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk()  + 0x15c bytes   
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction()  + 0x87 bytes   
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallRootFunction()  + 0xa9 bytes   
jscript9.dll!ScriptSite::CallRootFunction()  + 0x4f bytes   
jscript9.dll!ScriptSite::Execute()  + 0x5f bytes    
jscript9.dll!ScriptEngine::ExecutePendingScripts()  + 0xf328 bytes  
jscript9.dll!ScriptEngine::ParseScriptTextCore()  + 0x2d6 bytes 
jscript9.dll!ScriptEngine::ParseScriptText()  + 0x7a bytes  
mshtml.dll!CActiveScriptHolder::ParseScriptText()  + 0x3384 bytes   
mshtml.dll!CScriptCollection::ParseScriptText()  + 0x1fa bytes  
mshtml.dll!CScriptData::CommitCode()  - 0xfc bytes  
mshtml.dll!CMarkup::CommitQueuedScripts()  - 0x1c7625 bytes 
mshtml.dll!CMarkup::CommitQueuedScriptsInline()  - 0x18e954 bytes   
mshtml.dll!CMarkup::UnblockScriptExecutionHelper()  + 0x8d bytes    
mshtml.dll!CMarkup::UnblockScriptExecution()  + 0x63 bytes  
mshtml.dll!CScriptData::EnsureScriptDownloadLeft()  + 0x54 bytes    
mshtml.dll!CScriptData::OnDwnChan()  + 0x5a4 bytes  
mshtml.dll!CScriptData::OnDwnChanCallback()  + 0xe bytes    
mshtml.dll!CDwnChan::OnMethodCall()  + 0x1f bytes   
mshtml.dll!GlobalWndOnMethodCall()  + 0xf8 bytes    
mshtml.dll!GlobalWndProc()  + 0x451fa bytes 
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()  + 0x23 bytes  
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()  + 0xb7 bytes  
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageWorker@8()  + 0xed bytes 
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()  + 0xf bytes   
[Managed to Native Transition]  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg) + 0x20 bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame = {System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame}) + 0x94 bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0x37 bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run() + 0x20 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore) + 0x14 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x105 bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x24 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x1c bytes 
MyApp.exe!My.Namespace.App.Main() + 0x9c bytes
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly assembly, string[] args) + 0x9 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) + 0x61 bytes    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x27 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x6f bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx
```

Comment: `0xC0000005` usually refers to non-initialized memory

Comment: So how can I find the actual problem? I am not doing any manual memory management as I'm using C#.

Comment: This must not be necessarily you... Can be a bug, too...